# Problems with toggling more than one Image when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have my code set so that an image can change after clicking the image. I understand `getElementById` is meant to get results from one class name, but I don't know how to expand on that, and have the same result without changing the class name. I tried `querySelector`, but I think I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
<!--how do I make this apply to all images?-->
function changeImage() {
  let displayImage = document.querySelector('#img-area, #star-picture, #colorful')

  if (displayImage.src.match('Kabuto.jpg')) {
    displayImage.src = 'PersonalCreations/LylatForce.jpg'
  } else {
    displayImage.src = 'Kabuto.jpg'
  }
}
```

```html
<!--image area or main img-->

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img id="img-area" src='Kabuto.jpg' class="responsive" alt="" onclick="changeImage()" height="200" with="200">
        <button class="first" onclick="document.getElementById('img-area').src='PersonalCreations/LylatForce.jpg'">Change Image</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="star-picture" src="Kabuto.jpg" height="200" with="200" />
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('star- 
           picture').src='PersonalCreations/Year6969.jpg'">Change Image</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="colorful" src="Kabuto.jpg" height="200" with="500" />
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('colorful').src='PersonalCreations/BallInTheShoeProductions.jpg'">Change Image</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="holiday" src='Kabuto.jpg' alt="" onclick="changeImage()" height="200" with="200">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('holiday').src='PersonalCreations/ChristmasFestivalProject.jpg'">Change Image</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Hello World</p>

<script src="imgchanger.js"></script>
```

Comment: *I understand `getElementById` is meant to get results from one class name* <-- No, it's not. `getElementById()` does not have anything to do with class names. `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` do though.

Answer (score 0):

First, CSS styling and JavaScript should not be used inline with HTML. You should separate out those things.

Your issue is that you have:

```
let displayImage = document.querySelector ('#img-area, #star-picture, #colorful')
```

But, `.querySelector()` will only return the first matching element. You need `.querySelectorAll()`, which will return a collection of all matching elements.

Or, you can avoid all of that and do this:

```js
// Set up a single event handler for all clicks in the document
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){

  // But test to see if the click originated at a button
  if(evt.target.nodeName === "BUTTON"){

    // Get the button's parent div and then the source of the first img within that
    let img = evt.target.closest("div").querySelector("img").src;
    
    // Find out which button was clicked by looking at its class
    switch (evt.target.className){
      case "first":
        // Change the source
        img = "PersonalCreations/LylatForce.jpg"; 
        break;
      case "second":
        img = "PersonalCreations/Year6969.jpg"; 
        break;
      case "third":
        img = "PersonalCreations/BallInTheShoeProductions.jpg";       
        break;
      case "fourth":
        img = "PersonalCreations/ChristmasFestivalProject.jpg";     
        break;      
    }
    console.clear();
    console.log("Image source is now: " + img);
  }
});;
```

```css
.img200x200 { height:200px; width:200px; }
.img200x500 { height:200px; width:500px; }
```

```html
<!-- See how much cleaner the HTML is now that the CSS and 
     JavaScript have been separated out? -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">   
    <img src="Kabuto.jpg" class="responsive img200x200" alt="">
    <button class="first">Change Image</button>
  </div>     
  <div class="column">
    <img src="Kabuto.jpg" class="responsive img200x200" alt="">
    <button class="second">Change Image</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="Kabuto.jpg" class="responsive img200x500" alt="">
    <button class="third">Change Image</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="Kabuto.jpg" class="responsive img200x200" alt="">
    <button class="fourth">Change Image</button>
  </div> 
</div>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Hmmm. It's still not working for some reason. I was going to use the button, but I was planning to click the image to let the image switch.